# HMM: class residience time from time series

Tags: time-series, hidden-markov-model

I'm a newbie of the statistica subject. I've seen that HMM could be used in order to model state and state transitions for [time series](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3968966/) and, since I only know that in Markov Models I could state the residence time of each given state, I was wondering if that is also possible inside a HMM model. I am also saying that because the only paper where I've met a formal definition of such HMMs was [this one](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/CS4758/2012sp/materials/hmm_paper_rabiner.pdf). Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are interested in obtaining a HMM of the time series, then you will probably benefit from [this paper](https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~anoop/students/rzhang/rzhang_msc_thesis.pdf) about the use of HMM in the financial sector - see chapter 3.

**Prediction of financial time series with HMM by Yingjian Zhang.**

Abstract.

In this thesis, we develop an extension of the Hidden Markov Model (HMM) that addresses two of the most important challenges of nancial time series modeling: non-stationary and non-linearity. Specically, we extend the HMM to include a novel exponentially weighted EM algorithm to handle these two challenges. We show that this extension allows the HMM algorithm to model not only sequence data but also dynamic nancial time series.

Comment: Can you give a proper citation & a quick summary of the paper so that people will know if it's something they want to pursue & in case the link goes dead?

Comment: I am update comement